# Navigation with Tagbar

Tags: tags, filetype-c++, ctags, plugin-tagbar

I'm using [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) (with C++) and I would like to understand if and how it is possible to navigate the code as follow:

- Find all references of a variable or methods (where the variable or method is used/called... Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in Eclipse). It would be great if they would list in the Quickfix list.
- Leave *fixed* the Tagbar window while I moving around in my files. So I would like to have a toggle to stop Tagbar *following* me.
- Regenerate the tags from the root folder (the current folder when I opened Vim)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- A variety of methods are at your disposal

  - There are some very useful commands listed [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_a_variable/macro_definition), most notably `[I`, which will **display all lines in the current and all included files containing the keyword under the cursor**. See `:h [I` and `:h include-search`.
  - You can `:grep` or `:vimgrep` to search for occurrences of a particular symbol (or any pattern for that matter), and the results will be loaded into the Quickfix (or location) list which you can browse using `:copen` (or `:lopen`). See `:h :grep`. There is also [`Ag.vim`](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim).
  - You could make use of cscope, as suggested in the first part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616315/1208424) to a similar question
- Try `:TagbarTogglePause`.
- Use one of the handful of tag generation plugins floating around, or create a mapping that runs ctags. As far as Tagbar being able to do this for you, I'm uncertain. Browse `:h tagbar` and find out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I was looking for. Just another thing, is it possible to navigate the list of occurrence (found by [I) within the Quickfix List?

Comment: Not without doing something particularly roundabout, as far as I'm aware. Might be worth asking another question.